# 500 error on bluehost server for CakePHP application

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, bluehost

I have uploaded my application on bluehost server. I have uploaded it on public_html.

htacces on root
 /.htaccess permission 644

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

/app/.htaccess permission 644

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

/app/webroot/.htaccess permission 644

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

url is http://consumersinchrist.org/. Please help.

Comment: If you have a 500 error, you must check your Apache error log to see what it was.  It could be related to the .htaccess, or it could be a PHP error.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there's only a link to a site (which now works) and no log information.

Answer (score 1):

Go to cpanel->PHPConfig and enable FastCGI , it will work like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new host for you?  When I switch hosts, there's usually a unique small configuration that needs to be done to get my custom apps to work.

Check out these links from BlueHost:

[Help 1](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/123)
[Help 2](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/594)